# Закодировать java-программу под Linux

Tags: защита, java, linux

Чем можно закодировать программу, чтобы её трудно было подвергнуть реверс инжинирингу и таким образом не возможно было увидеть логику программы?

Мои программы не имеют GUI интерфейса. простые консольные программы производящие некоторые вычисления и завершающие свою роботу.

Comment: с защитой кода для java дела обстоят точно так же как и в других языках. от настоящего "взломщика" защитится сложно. 
java class'ы легко декомпилируются. даже после обфускации легко написать програмку которая будет возвращать код к виду хотя бы компилируемому (т.к. обфусцированый код после декомпиляции обычно не компилится ).
после чего можно его уже анализировать и работать с ним.
если б мне действительно понадобилось скрыть код от кого-то я бы использовал технологии типа EJB, где клиент работает только с предоставленым ему интерфейсом, даже без доступа к классам имплементаций

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать программу запутанной в коде правда будет неудобно

Ну и [обфусцировать](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: да! мне нужна обфускация!!!
на странице http://www.xakep.ru/magazine/xa/053/066/3.asp нашел список программ делающих это. не все под линуксом работают конечно, но! хоть что-то есть.

Comment: по поводу прогварда
 создал я примитивную программу вывести типа привет мир.
запускаю в консоле такой строкой

java -jar proguard.jar @q1.jar

и оно мне выводит 

Error: Unknown option 'PK' in line 1 of file 'q1.jar',
  included from argument number 1

посомтрел через шестнадцатеричный редактор - оказывается это начало jar-файла

Comment: Так почитайте вы как пользоваться. Зачем же беспредел-то городить? http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#application

Answer (score 1):

Обратите своё внимание на коммерческие обфускаторы. Они, в отличие от [progard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/), запутывают дизассемблеры достаточно хорошо. На мой взгляд [Zelix](http://www.zelix.com/) и [DashO](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dasho/overview) - хороший вариант. Вот список обфускаторов, который у меня есть:

- [ALLATORY](http://www.allatori.com/)
- [CodeShield](http://www.codingart.com/codeshield.html)
- [Crap4j](http://www.crap4j.org/forums.html)
- [DashO for Java](http://www.preemptive.com/dasho-java-obfuscator.html?source=Adwords&gclid=CIutxd_tkZYCFQxQtAodGj6EEA)
- [Inquartos](http://www.inquartos.ru/products/iob/)
- [Jarg](http://jarg.sourceforge.net/)
- [Java Code Protector](http://www.chainkey.com/en/prod.htm)
- [JBCO](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/JBCO/)
- [JCloak](http://www.force5.com/JCloak/ProductJCloak.html)
- [Jobfuscate](http://www.duckware.com/jobfuscate/index.html)
- [Jshrink](http://www.e-t.com/jshrink.html)
- [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)
- [RetroGuard](http://www.retrologic.com/retroguard-main.html)
- [Semdesigns](http://www.semdesigns.com/products/obfuscators/JavaObfuscator.html)
- [Smokescreen](http://www.leesw.com/smokescreen/)
- [The Marvin Obfuscator](http://www.drjava.de/obfuscator/)
- [YGuard](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yguard_about.html)
- [Zelix](http://zelix.com/)

Пользуйтесь!

Также я рекомендую ещё одно коммерческое решение - [Excelsior JET](http://www.excelsior.ru/products/jet.html). Это (и продуты такого типа), наверное, наиболее эффективная защита Java-программ.